# Eclipse: How do you remove an unrelated file from the build system

Tags: eclipse, build, makefile

I'm getting the following error trying to compile a project in Eclipse

```
Building file: ../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -I/usr/include/opencryptoki -I/usr/local/include/activemq-cpp-3.2.1 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client -I/usr/local/include/chilkat -I/usr/local/include -I/home/dmurry/Projects/GTP/src/Utilities -I/home/dmurry/Projects/GTP/src/Cto -I../GIM/Cto -I../GIM/Utilities -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -m32 -MMD -MP -MF".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.d" -MT".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.d" -o ".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.o" "../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.c"
cc1: error: ../GIM/Cto: Not a directory
cc1: error: ../GIM/Utilities: Not a directory
make: *** [.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.o] Error 1
```

But, I do not even have a `specs.c` file in my project.  So for some reason Eclipse is including this file in the build.

I am running:

```
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627
OS: Linux
```

Does anyone know how to exclude the file `../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.c` from the build?

Comment: This seems to be more a problem with the Eclipse build system than with make itself. I don't know anything about Eclipse, except that it stuffs some hidden files all over the place. Did you try to "regenerate" (or whatever it is called) the project ? Maybe starting a new project, and adding your source files. Is that an option?

Comment: Other advice: I don't use any more the build system provided with the IDE but use them **only** for editing purposes. To build an app, my opinion is that using a manually written makefile gives you much more control: no nonsense errors like the one you describe.

Comment: I agree, we actually do have separate makefiles that we use for builds, but I still like the ease of running the application using the run button in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

I deleted the **.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core** directory located in the project directory and it fixed the problem.

**Long Answer**

I looked in the makefile located in the Debug directory and found the following information:

```
################################################################################ 
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit! 
################################################################################ 

-include ../makefile.init 

RM := rm -rf 

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here 
-include sources.mk 
-include .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/subdir.mk 
-include subdir.mk 
-include objects.mk
```

The line that interested me was **-include .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/subdir.mk**

After doing some more digging around I looked into the hidden directory **.metadata** located in the project folder.  After looking in the .metadata directory I found the **.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core** directory, which contained the specs.c file.

I deleted the **.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core** directory.  Did a build and the problem went away.  The **-include .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/subdir.mk** was no longer being included in the build.